# Is there a filter option in Intellij Live Templates Editor?

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, filter, live

There is a lot of Live Templates in Intellij Live Template Editor for a lot different programming languages. I would like to see only templates that matters for Java. Is there a way to filter the template list and show only Java templates?

I couldn't find any option in the Intellij Settings. Maybe there is a hidden one somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for the corresponding feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189232).